# Puppet: conditional definition of types

Tags: puppet

I am not sure how to word this questions so please suggest an edit if you feels its inappropriate.

I am trying to extend existing puppet modules with support of different OS. I have ran out into a small problem which I am not sure how I could solve in an elegant way. In `params.pp` file there is such definition of OS-specific packages to install:

```
case $::osfamily {
  'RedHat': {
    $package_server = 'mariadb-server'
    $package_client = 'mariadb'
    $php_package_name = 'php-mysql'
  }
...
```

The module is written in such way that whole configuration depends on having `$php_package_name` installed. I want to exnted this module for different OS, which does not have a separate mysql package for php, thus I set `$php_package_name` variable to `undef`. This brings a problem, that puppet tries to install `Package[undef]`.

What would be a good way to prevent it? My thoughts so far war setting it to false and have whole definition of `$php_package_name` fire only `if $php_package_name != false`. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Setting the `$php_package_name` to `false` is a solution, that will work 50% of time. The other 50% times you will have the if `$php_package_name != false` evaluated first, and `$php_package_name = false` only later: unfortunately Puppet doesn't use the information where a variable is defined and where it is used to do a correct variable definitons' parsing. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/590762/how-to-ensure-that-the-if-statement-gets-parsed-before-a-given-resource-clas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that seems like a reasonable approach.  I'd suggest a slight variation on that, add a new param which determines whether the `package` resource which uses `$php_package_name` should be applied at all:

```
case $::osfamily {
  'RedHat': {
    $package_server = 'mariadb-server'
    $package_client = 'mariadb'
    $php_package_name = 'php-mysql'
    $php_package_install = true
  }
  'otherOS': {
    $package_server = 'mariadb-server'
    $package_client = 'mariadb'
    $php_package_install = false
  }
  ...
```

Then where the resource is:

```
if $thismodule::params::php_package_install {
  package { $thismodule::params::php_package_name:
    ensure => present,
    ...
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the method of doing all of your OS-specific stuff in params.pp might not end up being cleaner if the resources needed for the install on the new OS are wildly different; that might just turn your manifest file into an unreadable rat's nest of conditions and parameters. In that case, don't be afraid to just split the different OS off into a separate class (such as `install_el.pp` for the RedHat family and `install_otheros.pp` for the new family, with the correct one being included from `init.pp` or `params.pp`).

Comment: Are you sure it will work 100% of times? I am not sure one can rely on the order in which the variables are parsed. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/590762/how-to-ensure-that-the-if-statement-gets-parsed-before-a-given-resource-clas

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Yeah - the module he's modifying (and my recommendation to change it) is using the "params pattern", which relies on class inheritance to ensure correct evaluation order.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly answers my question. By the way, I already have `$php_package_ensure = 'present'`, can I just check that or do you suggest also having `$php_package_install`?

Comment: @edvinas.me Up to you - in my opinion it's clearer what's going on with a separate variable, but if nobody but you will be using this module then that's probably not a concern.